# RewriteRule returns not found if url/word is lowercase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Rewrite a url via htaccess but if I write it with lowercase or not exactly us it is inside the RewriteRule won't work, returns that the file or object not found. Example if I write go to url `ACTIVATE/TheTokenKey` returns not found. Is there anything that will read the url to lowercase, So if we write `AcTivAtE` will read it as `activate`.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Activation/(.*)$ ?tab=activation&token=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `[NC]` flag on your rule

```
RewriteRule ^Activation/(.*)$ ?tab=activation&token=$1 [NC,L]
```

> Use of the [NC] flag causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a
>   case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters
>   appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html